# Image Quality Assessment: MAPE and MSE

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics

I am evaluating the quality of two different images, compared to a reference image. These two images are obtained with two different importance sampling methods in path tracing. 
Looking at the most recent SIGGRAPH papers, I saw both MAPE and MSE are used. 
In my evaluation, these are the results:
**Image 1** 
MAPE(reference, image1) = 0.71 
MSE(reference, image1) = 100.38 
 
**Image 2** 
MAPE(reference, image2) = 0.73 
MSE(reference, image2) = 99

In Image 1, the MAPE score is better, but the MSE is worse. What's the meaning of this?
Here's how I calculate both measures:

```
def MSE(img1, img2):      
        squared_diff = (img1 -img2) ** 2
        mse = np.sum(squared_diff) / (3 * img1.shape[0] * img1.shape[1])    # RGB channels
        return mse
```

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / (y_true+0.001)))
```

EDIT: correct mistake

Comment: The MSE for image1 is worse than for image2 because an MSE closer to zero is better.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the opposite. Now my question is correct, thanks.